# AHK to parse the JSON Data

Tags: json, autohotkey

My JSON data will be similar to what mentioned in the below snippet.

```
{"members":[{"name":"Ben","occupation":"Police","age":"30"},{"name":"Tony","occupation":"Singer","age":"23"},{"name":"Lucy","occupation":"Artist","age":"27"},{"name":"Mark","occupation":"Lawyer","age":"40"},{"name":"Amy","occupation":"Doctor","age":"41"}]}
```

I have a requirement to get the name of the **person** whose occupation is **Police** from the JSON file.

Code I have written

```
#Include JSON.ahk

jsonStr={"members":[{"name":"Ben","occupation":"Police","age":"30"},{"name":"Tony","occupation":"Singer","age":"23"},{"name":"Lucy","occupation":"Artist","age":"27"},{"name":"Mark","occupation":"Lawyer","age":"40"},{"name":"Amy","occupation":"Doctor","age":"41"}]}

MyData := JSON.Load(jsonStr)

MsgBox, % MyData.members.1.name
```

The problem with the above code is I have to hard code the position of the dictionary ( MyData.members.1.name ) to get the result .

Is there anyway , to lookup for Police in the members list and return the name of the Person?

Can someone please help

Comment: I just wanted to thank you for showing me how to extract array elements from `JSON.Load()` using integers (i.e. the `1` in `members.1.name`). I've been banging my head on my desk for hours. I don't see that information anywhere so no idea how people know to do this

Answer (score 2):

You may use a for loop:

```
#Include JSON.ahk

jsonStr={"members":[{"name":"Ben","occupation":"Police","age":"30"},{"name":"Tony","occupation":"Singer","age":"23"},{"name":"Lucy","occupation":"Artist","age":"27"},{"name":"Mark","occupation":"Lawyer","age":"40"},{"name":"Amy","occupation":"Doctor","age":"41"}]}

MyData := JSON.Load(jsonStr)

for i, obj in MyData
{
    for k, v in obj
    if (v.occupation = "Police")
    {
        MsgBox % v.name
    }       
}
```